# How do i add integer values to Neo4j Node Property, using cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to store some nodes which have integers, how do i make neo4j understand that the characters i am sending are integers.

I tried

```
MATCH (a:Venture_capital),(b:Organization)
WHERE a.name = "Google"  AND int(b.from) = "2004" AND String(b.member) = "John L. Hennessy"
CREATE (a)-[:board_members]->(b)-[:organization]->(a)
```

and

```
MATCH (a:Venture_capital),(b:Organization)
WHERE a.name = "Google"  AND b.from = int("2004") AND b.member = String("John L. Hennessy")
CREATE (a)-[:board_members]->(b)-[:organization]->(a)
```

Both are not working. :(

How am i supposed to do that?

Neo4j does not allow me to store datetime and spatial data by default that's weird.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how, exactly, they are not working?  Do you encounter errors, or unexpected behavior, or...?

Comment: You say "I want to store some nodes which have integers", and yet according to your Cypher query the nodes already exist. Does the `from` property contain an integer or a string? And what do you mean by "sending" -- is "2004" an example of what you are "sending"?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
toFloat(5)
```

This is a workaround, more details see ["Provide a way to set properties with Integer (not Long) values in Cypher #7652"](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7652) on github.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toInt(string)`

```
MATCH (a:Venture_capital),(b:Organization)
WHERE a.name = "Google"  AND b.from = toInt("2004") 
  AND b.member = "John L. Hennessy"
CREATE (a)-[:board_members]->(b)-[:organization]->(a)
```

Comment: are those values really stored as integers or longs?

Comment: @manonthemat Neo4j internally uses 64-bit long and double values, so the `toInt()` function name is misleading.